# Capture microphone using GetUserMedia

Tags: html5-audio, microphone, getusermedia

I am using GetUserMedia to capture user input(audio) through microphone on Chrome, but the problem is that now I want to capture the input from independent microphone (not local one built-in pc). Does anyone know how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess currently Chrome allows audio input capture only through built-in microphone.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the default input in your system settings.

Comment: I think following steps should be also done (although still is not working for me):
Go to Settings.
Click 'Show advanced settings'
In the "Privacy" section, click the Content settings button
Go to "media" and change to the microphone that needs to be used

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on your system? Windows or Mac? Are you plugging in to an audio jack, or using a USB device that requires a driver? What version of Chrome? Have you enabled "Web Audio Input" in `chrome://flags`?

Comment: I am using Windows 7, I have enabled the Web Audio Input, and I tried to change the default recording device but still didn't work. I had to restore my PC cause none of previous settings (internal mic) did not work after installing drivers of the new microphone.